# Sheaf of differential and its reflexive hull on a toric variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a non-smooth toric variety, $\Omega_X$ be the sheaf of differentials, $\hat{\Omega}_X$ the double dual of $\Omega_X$. My questions are:

1. Is there any chance that $\Omega_X=\hat{\Omega}_X$?
2. If 1 is not true, is there any chance that we can relate the cohomology of the two sheaves?
3. If 1 and 2 does not have an answer in general, hwo about weighted projective spaces?

Comment: This doesn't quite answer your question, but it's related.  See the main theorems in arXiv:1003.2913.  Keeping in mind that normal toric varieties are always Kawamata log terminal.

In particular, the pushdown of the sheaf of differentials from a resolution of a toric variety should satisfy this property.  

S\'andor will likely give more specifics.

Comment: Just a quick comment, in some sources the sheaf $\hat{\Omega}_X$ is called the ``Zariski-de Rham differentials''. This might help you find more sources..

Comment: @Karl, I always wondered if these have an "official" name. We usually just call them *reflexive differentials*.

Answer (score 3):

1) No, this usually does not happen. Take the singularity $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$. Then 
$$xdx+ ydy+zdz=0$$ and hence one obtains that 
$$\eta:=\frac{xdz-zdx}y=\frac{zdy-ydz}x.$$
Now this implies that $\eta$ is a differential form that is defined on the complement of the singular point and hence it is in the reflexive hull, but it cannot be extended into the singular point. So $\Omega_X$ is not reflexive.

2/3) There is of course the natural map $\Omega_X\to \hat\Omega_X$, so there is a map on cohomology, but

4) Why would you want to know the cohomology of $\Omega_X$? The interesting sheaf here is the reflexive hull of $\Omega_X$, that is, in your notation, $\hat\Omega_X$. As Karl points out that has the nice property that it is isomorphic to $\pi_*\Omega_{\widetilde X}$ if $\pi:\widetilde X \to X$ is a resolution of singularities. It also is the sheaf whose cohomology appears in the Hodge structure of these singularities. (Along with the reflexive hulls of $\Omega_X^p$ which are also isomorphic to $\pi_*\Omega_{\widetilde X}^p$ by the paper Karl quoted above).

Comment: Well, it is kind of a long story why I am interested in $\Omega_X$ rather than its reflexsive hull. Roughly speaking because the deformation theory is controlled by $\Omega_X$. I am trying to understand the deformation of a pair $(X, D)$. A question I asked a few days ago is here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45343/deformation-and-obstruction-of-a-pair-x-d

The divisor $D$ is isomorphic to a (rather singular, but normal) weighted hypersurface in a weighted projective space. (But $X$ is not the weighted projective space!) So I am trying to relate the cohomology of D to the w.p.s.

Comment: It seems like there is an upper bound on how many words one can use in a comment. Let me explain a little more.

Basically I need an isomorphism between $H^i(Ext(\Omega_D, \mathcal{O}_D)$ to $H^{i+2}(Hom(\Omega_D, \mathcal{O}_D))$. One way to do this is to try to relate these to the ambient weighted projective space.

Comment: I was going to say (after your first comment) that you need $Ext$ and not the cohomology of $\Omega$, which is a trivial comment, but explains why I asked what I asked in the answer...